# Why is execv doesn't work in sort command

Tags: c, linux

Hi I'm trying to use `execv` function in forked child process to execute the commands like: `ls`, `grep`, `sort`, `awk` and so on in terminal.
However, `ls`, `grep` works but `sort`, `awk` and other things are not working and `execv` returns `-1` for failure.
Inputs for `argv` was `"sort t.txt"` by `stdin` and `argv[0]=sort`, `argv[1]=t.txt`. When I put in `grep 5 t.txt` for example, it printed out 3 numbers in t.txt that includes 5 and `ls` printed out every file in directory. Why do only `ls` and `grep` work and rest of commands don't?

```c
    char* command(char** argv) {
       char* ptr = malloc(200);
       if (!strcmp(argv[0], "ls") || !strcmp(argv[0], "man") || !strcmp(argv[0], "grep")
        || !strcmp(argv[0], "sort") || !strcmp(argv[0], "awk") || !strcmp(argv[0], "bc")) {
           sprintf(ptr, "/bin/%s", argv[0]);
       }
       return ptr;
    }
    
    //inside fork=
    char* pos = command(argv);
    if (execv(pos, argv) < 0) {
       printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
       if(argv[1]!=NULL)
          printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
       if(argv[2]!=NULL)
          printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
       perror("execv");
       fprintf(stderr, "%s: Command not found.\n", argv[0]);
       free(pos);
       exit(0);
    }
    free(pos);
```

```
   mini> sort t
   sort
   t
   execv: No such file or directory
   sort: Command not found.
   mini> ls
   Makefile  minishell.c  pa2  t
   mini>
```

Comment: If `execv` fails, use e.g. `perror` to print the actual error, or use `strerror(errno)` to get it as a printable string.

Comment: Also, is your `argv` array properly terminated with a `NULL` pointer? And please show the actual contents of the `argv` array if `execv` fails.

Comment: mini> sort t
sort
t
execv: No such file or directory
sort: Command not found.
mini> ls
Makefile  minishell.c  pa2  t
mini>
I found it can't find file 't' by using perror thank you. As it shows, argv is sort, t, null. I'm sure the end is null because when I change stdin to argv, I added null in code

Comment: I don't have a `/bin/sort` in my system. It's `/usr/bin/sort`. Why don't you use `execvp` to execute any commands in the `PATH`? Then you can skip the `command` function.

Comment: I never have used execvp, but I'll try. Thank you

Comment: It's exactly the same as `execv`, but uses the `PATH` environment variable to find the commands. So `execvp(argv[0], argv)` should work just fine if the command is in the path.

Comment: "Inputs for argv was "sort t.txt" by stdin and argv[0]=sort, argv[1]=t.txt." That does not fit together. Arguments are not related to `stdin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you hard-code the commands to be found in `/bin/`, and some commands (like the `sort` command) isn't in that location (`sort` is typically in `/usr/bin/`).

To solve that problem, and to be able to use *any* command in the standard path, use `execvp` instead:

```
execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

The difference from `execv` is that `execvp` will use the environment variable `PATH` to search for the command.

Please read [the `exec` family manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) for details about the different versions.